# ng-grid changing style on populating data and making visible

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I'm schooling up on Angularjs' ng-grid component and have encountered a rather disappointing issue. Basically, the flow is this: page loads and only a button is visible. Button is clicked and AJAX request gets json data and binds it to the grid.

This is what I see when I first click the button:
[image]

If I resize the browser at all, it snaps back into the correct size:
[image]

My controller looks like this:

```
myAppModule.controller('PodcastController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getData = function () {
        $http.get('/Home/PodcastDataAsJson').success(function (data) {
            $scope.podcasts = data;
        });

        $scope.gridVisibilty = 'gridStyle';
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'podcasts',
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'Id', displayName: 'Id' },
            { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name' },
            { field: 'Artist', displayName: 'Artist' }
        ]
    };

    $scope.gridVisibilty = 'notDisplayed';

});
```

The View looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="gridExampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="PodcastController">

        <button ng-click="getData()">Click to get Data</button>

        <div id="datagrid" ng-grid="gridOptions" class="ng-class: gridVisibilty;"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My css looks like this:

```
.notDisplayed 
{
    display: none;
}

.displayed 
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
}

.gridStyle 
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

I'd like to know whether this is me, or whether it is a bug that I should lodge with the Angular ng-grid peeps.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show how you load the ng-grid stylesheet but I had similar problems when I tried to get it with a direct link.

Here is a demo with a local file for the ng-grid stylesheet: http://plnkr.co/edit/2pq9YotA4RJIMll5BJvh?p=preview. I also used the ng-show directive binded to the podcasts variable as the condition to show/hide the grid.

In the head of index.html, if you try to use the direct link to the stylesheet, there is a weird display effect. But if you put the same code in a local file, it works.

Comment: you rock! ng-show totally sorted it out. Thanks for the assist. Have a great week!